# How do I compute the subgroup of $(\Bbb Z_{17}^\times, *_{17})$ generated by $\{2,3\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I compute the subgroup of $(\Bbb Z_{17}^\times, *_{17})$ generated by $\{2,3\}$, where $\Bbb Z_{17}^\times = \{1,2,3,\dots,16\}$?

I believe I understand how to calculate it for all the cyclical subgroups but I'm not too sure how to do it with this criteria. I've tried finding similar examples but go off but I couldn't seem to find any.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What does `*17` mean?

Comment: It's just Z17 without 0 included and *17 is just multiplication (mod 17)

Comment: Well, it's usually denoted  $(\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z)^\times$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. The notation in the book I have must be different than standard notation

Comment: @Richard Meyers, it is totally fine to write it as you did. $\mathbb{Z_n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are two isomorphic groups and they are being treated as the same thing. I usually prefer to write $\mathbb{Z_n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can check that $3$ alone generates the whole group $(\mathbb{Z_{17}})^{\times}$. So $2$ and $3$ together generate the whole group for sure.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

By *Lagrange's theorem*, the order of the subgroup $\langle 2,3\rangle$ is a divisor of $16$, and it contains the subgroups generated by $2$ and by $3$, so it is divisible by the orders of these subgroups. What are their orders?  Do they contain the same elements?